# Removing all characters except digits from clipboard

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, copy-paste, automation

I'm trying to refine a script I use within an Automator program and I would appreciate your help on this.

The program is designed to mark a telephone number into clipboard make a tel:link and send it to an telephone application, which works fine.
I only have a problem if the marked phonenumber looks something like this: +49(1)123/12345 because then I have to remove all the special characters and leave only the digits and the + in front of the number.

The problem is I'm not that good at scripting, so how to do it?

Comment: See answer below. If you need help in integrating this into whatever you already have please add the relevant parts of it to the question (for Automator, screenshots are fine).

Comment: This should be a comment, but I have not enough reputation yet. Removing all special characters of "+49 (0)30 12345-67" (common format in Germany and Austria) would result in an invalid number. The number is either "030 123 1234567" (inside Germany) or "+49 30 1234567" (outside Germany), but removing every special characters results in "490301234567" (note the extra "0") which is not the same number.

Comment: @andii1997 good point! Which is why one never should use the +49[0)30 notation, especially because nowadays phone systems are smart enough to do the right thing when dialing +4930… within Germany.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The shell snippet

```
pbpaste | tr -cd "[:digit:]+" | pbcopy
```

will take the content of the clipboard, remove all non-digits and put the result back into the clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

An AppleScript solution:

```
set the clipboard to the words of (the clipboard) as text
```

Comment: Without seeing the workflow it's hard to say which of the two answer so far are better, but a +1 is in order nonetheless.

Comment: I'd say the shell snippet is the "catch all" solution that will work in the instances where there are letters as well, e.g. if the OP copied a person's name and number to the clipboard.  But, if it's only to cater for the non-digits that typically can be found in telephone numbers, then this is fine.

Comment: Does this answer leave the + sign behind, per the requirements?

Comment: @trlkly, Yes it does; however, this method is only good if what's on the clipboard is e.g. `+49(1)123/12345 `. If it e.g. `John Doe +49(1)123/12345 ` it will return: `JohnDoe+49112312345` So as CJK mentioned in his comment "I'd say the shell snippet is the "catch all" solution that will work in the instances where there are letters as well".